# Dynamically Change Form Action Based on Selection Using jQuery - problem with default submission

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have simple form with email options field.
I wanted to do Dynamically Change Form Action Based on Selection Using jQuery and it works fine.

The only problem is that if you do not select with click one of options 'Motoristi' / 'Navtika' nothing happens. I want default action to work.

```
<html>
  <script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
      // Function to change form action.
      $("#db").change(function () {
        var selected = $(this).children(":selected").text();
        switch (selected) {
          case "Motoristi":
            $("#myform").attr('action', 'https://kmc.us20.list-manage.com/subscribe/post?u=90bdfa6b0ea17ba9839f78143&id=75956a3bb4');

            break;
          case "Navtika":
            $("#myform").attr('action', 'https://kmc.us20.list-manage.com/subscribe/post?u=90bdfa6b0ea17ba9839f78143&id=2463b3ce5c');
            break;

          default:
            $("#myform").attr('action', 'https://kmc.us20.list-manage.com/subscribe/post?u=90bdfa6b0ea17ba9839f78143&id=75956a3bb4');
        }
      });

      // Function For Back Button
      $(".back").click(function () {
        parent.history.back();
        return false;
      });
    });     
  </script>
  <div id="main">
    <div id="first">
      <form id="myform" method="post" name="myform">
        <label>E-poštni naslov:</label>
        <input type="email" value="" name="EMAIL" class="required email" id="mce-EMAIL" required>
        <label>Zanimanje:</label>
        <select id="db">
          <option>Motoristi</option>
          <option>Navtika</option>
        </select>
        <input class="submit" id="submit" type="submit" value="Submit">
      </form>
    </div>
  </div>
</html>
```

Comment: just require your select

Comment: oh nvm i just understood the problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The switch statement is only triggered after the `change` event is triggered on your select. So by default, your form doesn't have a action. In order to give your form a default action, give the form an `action` attribute. When one of the cases in your switch is selected, the actions changes. If none of the cases was matched, nothing happens. So:

```
<form id="myform" method="post" name="myform" action="https://kmc.us20.list-manage.com/subscribe/post?u=90bdfa6b0ea17ba9839f78143&amp;id=75956a3bb4">
    <!-- rest of your form -->
</form>
```

and the switch just like this:

```
switch (selected) {

    case "Motoristi":
        $("#myform").attr('action', 'https://kmc.us20.list-manage.com/subscribe/post?u=90bdfa6b0ea17ba9839f78143&amp;id=75956a3bb4');
        alert("Form Action is Changed to 'mysql.html'n Press Submit to Confirm");
    break;
    case "Navtika":
        $("#myform").attr('action', 'https://kmc.us20.list-manage.com/subscribe/post?u=90bdfa6b0ea17ba9839f78143&amp;id=2463b3ce5c');
        alert("Form Action is Changed to 'oracle.html'n Press Submit to Confirm");
    break;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your switch / case is only executed if a user clicks change the dropdown. If the dropdown won't be changed, nothing happens.

Just add the form default action straight to your form and replace it, if a user change the select.

```
<form id="myform" method="post" name="myform" action="YOUR DEFAULT ACTION">
```

And then replace in your cases:

```
$("#myform").attr('action', 'https://kmc.us20.list-manage.com/subscribe/post?u=90bdfa6b0ea17ba9839f78143&amp;id=75956a3bb4');
```

Answer (score 0):

## A Few Corrections

1. Set `<form>` `[action]` to default value because the user could skip `<select>` and there's would be no default otherwise.
2. Add a default `<option>` at the first position.
3. Add `value` to each `<option>`
4. Use the `<select>` directly to get the selected value.

   - `var selected = $('#db').val()`
5. Use `confirm()` instead of `alert()`

   - When user clicks `OK` set `<form>` `[action]` to new value and `return`.
   - When user clicks `Cancel` set `<select>` to default: `$('#db').val('')`
6. Use template literals instead of string literals.

   - TL: Wrap with <kbd>`` ` ``</kbd> ex. `string of text`
   - TL: can have multiple lines

---

### Suggestions

- Use a semantic element when possible.

  - `<main>`, `<section>`, and `<fieldset>` was added to define hierarchy and purpose. On a more technical reason is that styles can be assigned more fluidly.
- I changed id of `<form>` to `#main` from `#myForm`. There's no advantage doing so, it's just that I hate anything named `my*` it's just my opinion.

---

### Demo

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  // Function to change form action.
  $("#db").change(function() {
    var selected = $(this).val();
    switch (selected) {
      case "Motoristi":
        if (window.confirm(`
        Form Action is Changed to 'mysql.html'
        Press OK to Confirm.
        `)) {
          $("#main").attr('action', 'https://kmc.us20.list-manage.com/subscribe/post?u=90bdfa6b0ea17ba9839f78143&id=75956a3bb4');
          return;
        }
        $(this).val('');
        break;

      case "Navtika":
        if (window.confirm(`
        Form Action is Changed to 'oracle.html' 
        Press OK to Confirm.
        `)) {
          $("#main").attr('action', 'https://kmc.us20.list-manage.com/subscribe/post?u=90bdfa6b0ea17ba9839f78143&id=2463b3ce5c');
          return;
        }
        $(this).val('');
        break;

      default:
        $("#main").attr('action', 'https://kmc.us20.list-manage.com/subscribe/post?u=90bdfa6b0ea17ba9839f78143&id=75956a3bb4');
        break;
    }
  });

  // Function For Back Button
  $(".back").click(function() {
    parent.history.back();
    return false;
  });
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head></head>

<body>
  <main>
    <section class="first">
      <form id="main" action='https://kmc.us20.list-manage.com/subscribe/post?u=90bdfa6b0ea17ba9839f78143&id=75956a3bb4' name="main" method="post">
        <fieldset>
          <label>E-poštni naslov:</label>
          <input type="email" value="" name="EMAIL" class="required email" id="mce-EMAIL" required><br>
          <label>Zanimanje:</label>
          <select id="db">
            <option value=''>Odaberite zanimanje</option>
            <option value='Motoristi'>Motoristi</option>
            <option value='Navtika'>Navtika</option>
          </select>
          <input type="submit">
        </fieldset>
      </form>
    </section>
  </main>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```